# chained select jquery php mysql repeat

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, select

Sample MySql Table (There is an id column also) :

```
+----------------------------------+
| one  | two | three | four | five |
+----------------------------------+
| v1   | v2  | v3    | v4   | v9   |
+----------------------------------+
| v1   | v2  | v6    | v8   | v9   |
+----------------------------------+
| v1   | v7  | v6    | v4   | v10  |
+----------------------------------+
| v11  | v7  | v12   | v4   | v10  |
+----------------------------------+
| v11  | v2  | v3    | v8   | v5   |
+----------------------------------+
```

[Here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) how is the plugin works.

I want to make 5 chained selectboxes using values from mysql. I can make output like this with using a simple query;

```
$result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4))
  {
  echo '<option value="'.$row4['four'].'" class="'.$row4['three'].'">'.$row4['four'].'</option>';
  }
```

It gives this;

```
<select id="model" name="model">
  <option value="">--</option>   
  <option value="v4" class="v3">v4</option>
  <option value="v4" class="v6">v4</option>
  <option value="v4" class="v12">v4</option>
  <option value="v8" class="v6">v8</option>
  <option value="v8" class="v3 v6">v8</option>
</select>
```

But there are some values that repeat. A "three" has more than one "two" for example. Output should be like this;

```
<select id="model" name="model">
  <option value="">--</option>   
  <option value="v4" class="v3 v6 v12">v4</option>
  <option value="v8" class="v6 v3">v8</option>
</select>
```

How can i make this? (multiple class names based on table rows)

Comment: How does this "series-x" and "aY" stuff relate to `v1`, `v2`, etc... in your example table?

Comment: @MarcB one > two > three > four > five
When user select first select that contains "one"s, other select should show "two"s with selected "one". But selects wont have multiple options with same value (this part where i stuck). Outputs are from examples on plugin page.

Comment: still makes no sense whatsoever to me...

Comment: @MarcB I edited samples according to table. How can i make output like second?

Comment: this'd be the quick workaround: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: @MarcB How will this help?

Comment: @MarcB Ok, i own results now. What about if values have spaces too?

Comment: Then you're hosed. css class names cannot have spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use the class `v3 v6 v12` , and use `GROUP by`  to get your desired result
then use this sql instead

```
   $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT one ,two,group_concat(three SEPARATOR ' ') three, four , five FROM table_1 group by four ");
```

[**DEMO SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/461d2/7)

Comment: i dont know if this helped you or ?

Comment: Thanks but this won't help. Check the question comments. That jQuery plugin working with class for relationship. And i have spaces in values.

Comment: you mean this one in the class have spaces? if yes then my code is right , it gives you values with spaces . have you tried it?

Comment: Table values have spaces. v3 v6 are just sample. Values are like

Information / About Pass / Password Reset / ..